# Improving Elasticsearch indexing performance

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, optimization, filebeat

I'm trying to improve my ES (version 8.3.3) indexing performance.

I have a 2-node cluster (on 2 physical servers, each with 96 CPUs and 755GB RAM), and I have set the number of shards to 4, replicas to 0, and the index to rollover at 40GB (it'll rollover every 30 minutes or so). There are 2 filebeat instances pushing data to the same ES.

I was wondering that no matter how many nodes I have in my ES cluster, all my data can only be written to one index. Is this where the number of shards would help to parallelize the writing to the index?

I have seen a slight improvement by increasing the number of shards from 2 to 4, where the highest indexing rate seen increased from ~33K/s to ~41K/s, but there is still packet drop being reported in my filebeat logs.

At the same time, I've read that having too many shards would decrease search performance.

My question is, for an index size of 40GB, how many shards should I set, without too much degradation in the search performance?

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering that no matter how many nodes I have in my ES cluster, all my data can only be written to one index. Is this where the number of shards would help to parallelize the writing to the index?

Yes. The primary shard counts will help you to parallelize the process, especially the indexing. But of course, it's limited to the hardware itself. Elasticsearch can be as fast as your hardware. So maybe you can switch to SSD disks if you don't have already. Also the RAID type effect the performance to much.

> My question is, for an index size of 40GB, how many shards should I set, without too much degradation in the search performance?

In the best practice, it's recommended to keep a shard size between [10-50GB](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/size-your-shards.html#:%7E:text=There%20are%20no%20hard%20limits,Search%20and%20similar%20use%20cases.). The shard sizes are already in that range, you can check the following recommendations.

## Recommendation:

1. Build a VM on 2 physical servers, set max RAM to 62GB of RAM, and
   set heap to 31GB. You will have 12 nodes per physical server. It
   will perform better.
2. Have dedicated master nodes at least 3 with 4GB of RAM.
3. Have dedicated coordinator nodes and send all HTTP traffic through
   them.
4. Set refresh_interval to a higher number to speed up the indexing.

Some useful articles:
[Tune for indexing speed.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-indexing-speed.html)
[Tune for search speed.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-search-speed.html)

Comment: Another recommendation: Check the metrics of your cluster with Opster AutoOps, it's free to use for 2 weeks, https://autoops.opster.com/. Thanks to AutoOps, you can find the problematic query/index/node hot spot, heavy analyzers, and more.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still trying to understand the benefits of having multiple nodes in the cluster. It seems like the number of shards is the limiting factor. Say I find that 4 shards per index gives the best performance (but still not satisfactory), how does having more nodes help, as I can only write to 1 index each time, and can't increase the number of shards anymore (since it depends on index size).

Comment: Elasticsearch will perform with 12 nodes with 62GB of RAM node rather than 755GB of ram in one node.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-enterprise/2.0/ece-heap.html#ece_elasticsearch_clusters_and_jvm_heap_size

```What these recommendations mean is that on a 64 GB cluster, we dedicate 32 GB to the Elasticsearch heap and 32 GB to the operating system in the container that hosts your cluster. If you provision a 128 GB cluster, we create two 64 GB nodes, each node with 32 GB reserved for the Elasticsearch heap and 32 GB reserved for the operating system.```